# color detection

Tags: java, xml, colors, hex

I have XML file containing 2222 colors with two attributes first name and second rgb value(actully its hex value). 
I am trying to display the color name of position where user have clicked the mouse.  `String hexstring(parameter value)` is the hex value of user clicked color this value will be compare with `rgbvalue` (actully its hex value stored in XML file) if both matches then it displays the color name stored in XML file but my comparision `if` statement is not working

```
public static void xmlfilereader(String hexString)
    {  
    try{

       DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            File file = new File("colore.xml");
            if (file.exists()) {
                Document doc = db.parse(file);
                Element docEle = doc.getDocumentElement();

                System.out.println("Root element of the document: "
                        + docEle.getNodeName());

                NodeList colorList = docEle.getElementsByTagName("color");
               System.out.println("Total Color: " + colorList.getLength());

                if (colorList != null && colorList.getLength() > 0) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < colorList.getLength(); i++) {

                        Node node = colorList.item(i);                     

                        if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                           NodeList mycolorList = doc.getElementsByTagName("color");
                            Element colorElement = (Element) mycolorList.item(i);

                            String colorName = colorElement.getAttribute("name");
                            String rgbvalue = colorElement.getAttribute("rgb");

                                if(hexString.equalsIgnoreCase(rgbvalue) )
                                {
                                   System.out.println("color name: " + colorName + " Hex: " + rgbvalue);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    System.out.println("comparision if not working");
                                }
                      }
```

**output:**

```
Root element of the document: ColorDefinition

Total Color: 2222

comparision if not working

comparision if not working

comparision if not working
......
```

this code just compare with first color of xml file

Comment: Have you tried printing the values of `hexString` and  `rgbvalue` to see if they actually match? Chances are the way you retrieve the RGB value from XML is probably wrong somewhere. Paste your sample XML too.

Comment: *"`comparision if not working`"*  Egads!  Run a spell-checker on text an app. might be printing many times.  Also the 2nd word, `if` or `is`?

Comment: respected Andrew Thompson! Comparision if means the if statement of comparision.... its just message in else..